# Pattern matching incorrect

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

I'm kinda new to haskell

```
data Tree a = Leaf | Branch (Tree a) a (Tree a)
  deriving (Show, Eq)

insert :: (Ord a, Eq a) => a -> Tree a -> Tree a
insert x Leaf = Branch Leaf x Leaf
insert x (Branch l v r)
  | x <= v = Branch (insert x l) v r
  | x > v = Branch l v (insert x r)
```

The code gives the following warning (but compiles):

```
app\Main.hs:10:1: warning: [-Wincomplete-patterns]
    Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
    In an equation for `insert':
        Patterns not matched:
            _ (Branch Leaf _ Leaf)
            _ (Branch Leaf _ (Branch _ _ _))
            _ (Branch (Branch _ _ _) _ Leaf)
            _ (Branch (Branch _ _ _) _ (Branch _ _ _))
   |
10 | insert x Leaf = Branch Leaf x Leaf
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^...
```

Technically speaking `x <= v` and `x > v` should cover all possible alternatives, but I'm having this warning. I's actually fixed if I use `otherwise` in the second case, but shouldn't it work just like this?

Comment: By the way, `x <= v` and `x > v` do not cover all the possible alternatives on floating point values. There, we have NaN values and IEEE 754 mandates [both to be false on NaNs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN#Comparison_with_NaN). This is an (in-)famous "feature" which can be very surprising.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An `Ord` instance *should* define a total order, but Haskell is unable to enforce that as a requirement nor is it able to detect if an `Ord` instance is, indeed, a total order.

```
Prelude> data Foo = A | B deriving Eq
Prelude> instance Ord Foo where _ <= _ = False; _ > _ = False
Prelude> A <= B
False
Prelude> A > B
False
```

Using `otherwise` works not because it is `True` (which it is, by literal definition) when `x <= v` is `False`, but because it is `True` *regardless* of whether `x <= v` is true or false. Knowing that `<=` and `>` each *can* return `True` does not guarantee that one of them *will*.